Validate saml2 login response inside controller using spring security
I am trying to implement spring security in our exsisting project. Currently we are using Openam for saml authentication. The current architecture is we are triggering the saml authentication requests inside the Logincontroller. I am able to trigger the saml authentication as well using spring security inside the controller. But when I have to validate the saml response received from the IDP mapping the "login/saml2/sso" in the requestMapping for the controller is not working. As the filters are triggered before reaching the servlet.
Currently controller is
 @GetMapping("/samlLogin")
public void run(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, @RequestParm registrationId) throws IOException {
    RelyingPartyRegistration registration = this.registrations.getRelyingPartyRegistrationBasedOnId(registrationId);
    if(req.getParameter("SAMLResponse") == null) {
        resp.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/saml2/authenticate/" + registration.getRegistrationId());
    }
   else{
     //Get the response and validate not sure how as the point does not come to the controller for validating the response.

}
}
'''
